My web3 js transaction has a gas estimate of $0.02 displayed with rainbow wallet, but with metamask it displays as $2.00
The more accurate is $0.02, is there anything I can do to make metamask look better.
This is on base chain.

Can you share your code snippets using web3.js for both metamask and rainbow wallets?

@SYEDASADKAZMI answered my own question

const gasPrice = await web3.eth.getGasPrice(); // needed this line

const sendOptions = {
  from: account,
  value: amountInMax.toString(),
  gas: estimatedGas.toString(),
  maxPriorityFeePerGas: gasPrice.toString() // and this one
};

Metamask relies on site supplied maxPriorityFeePerGas it appears, when I added the above lines all is well.
